# Laravel error FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected '$content' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

I am new to laravel.
I wanted to create content of pages outside of Route::get as stated below and then from inside of Route::get call the variable

```
$content='This is our contact page';


Route::get('/contact', function($contentDetail=$content){

    return $contentDetail;

});
```

but I am getting the error

> **FatalErrorException**
>
> syntax error, unexpected '$content' (T_VARIABLE).

Pls how can i do what I want.

Comment: This is basic php syntax. Example 3 in https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 4):

Use `use($content)` like this,to pass variable `$content` inside callback

```
$content='This is our contact page';

Route::get('/contact', function()use($content){
   return $content;
});
```

Inside callback function it checks and takes value of url param like in url `/contact/{id?}`

First param in callback function will take value of `id` from url, if not found then it will set it to `5`

```
Route::get('/contact/{id?}', function($id=5){
    return "id : ".$id;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write like this:-

```
 Route::get('/contact', function(){
$content='This is our contact page';
    return $content;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to the variable to come from outside the function. I do not want to declare it inside the variable